# <unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'Swift': File name too long

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9

I updated my XCode from 6.4 to XCode 7 and now I get this error:
:0: error: opening import file for module 'Swift': File name too long

Now I'm unable to compile my project does anyone has an idea why is this happening? It shows this error for all my Swift Files.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, how long is the file name, not that the length has anything to do with the question and/or potential answer. 

Comment: Perhaps an errror was made updating the project. Just rool back to the last working version and try again watching very carefully what is happening.

Comment: they are actually small one is called UIViewExtension.swift I don't think that's the real cause I was thinking if the path might be too long or containing invalid characters but I can't find the real reason why is this happening I've been working on this for 1 day is driving me crazy it happen when I updated to XCode7 before that evertything was fine @zaph

Comment: Perhaps an error in a path, perhaps a stray quote character in the name/path? A non-matched quote in the path will keep the file name path from finding the end. Look at the full paths in the report navigator command-8, disclose everything and look very hard at the paths.

Comment: Ok thanks I will take a look to all the paths. @zaph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solve the problem. The issue when updated to Xcode7 was that the Framework Search Paths value $(SRCROOT)  was set to recursive. For some reason this was not working for me in Xcode7. I have $(SRCROOT) set to recursive in Xcode6.4 where it was working perfectly fine but after the update to Xcode7 it start to show:
:0: error: opening import file for module 'Swift': File name too long
I deleted $(SRCROOT) value and add $(PROJECT_DIR)/... paths for every library and framework used within my app. I tried to just set $(PROJECT_DIR) with recursive value but I would get the same compiling time error so the solution was just to specify the path to every library and framework used.

Hope this helps to other folks that have the same issue.

Comment: I am having this same issue, however this solution did not result the issue. I'm on Xcode 7.3.1.