# Opening import file for module 'Swift'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have added Objective c files to swift , I am getting following error :

> Opening import file for module 'Swift': Not a directory

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `build settings` for ALL targets (including the actual project) and remove any erroneous `paths from Framework Search Path.`

Specifically:

Simplified the main target to:

```
$(inherited)

$(SRCROOT)
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: I have added in all target , but still error is getting

Answer (score 0):

create **(ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h)** to your project root directory and there is no need to import objective c file to swift file and all the objective c files need to be import in **(ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h)** hope that will solve your problem.

for more info visit [Xcode not automatically creating bridging header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716413/xcode-not-automatically-creating-bridging-header)

Comment: I have added in Objective c bridging  Header

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639652/unknown0-error-opening-import-file-for-module-swift-file-name-too-long